# Combine tailwindcss with CSS modules

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app, styling, tailwind-css

I installed tailwindcss following this tutorial: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app (using Craco instead of postcss). After I included every code snippet and reloaded the webpage, all the default CSS styles were gone (h1, flex, etc.) Is it because I didn't configure tailwindcss with the whole project right or it's normal to have all the default styling rules deleted and you have to specify the base. By configuring I mean you just need to add:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

in index.css file only, not every .css component file.

Comment: Tailwind set it's own base styles. So you`ve done everything right. More information can be found here - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight

Answer (score 2):

[Tailwind Preflight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight) removes all of the default margins from elements like headings, blockquotes, paragraphs, etc.

```
@tailwind base; /* Preflight will be injected here */

@tailwind components;

@tailwind utilities;
```

If you would like to stick with default values, then you can disable Preflight

```
  // tailwind.config.js
  module.exports = {
    corePlugins: {
     preflight: false,
    }
  }
```